# Updating the time to live for a Solr document

Tags: solr

I have a Solr collection that uses the DocExpirationUpdateFactory:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain default="true">
  <processor class="solr.processor.DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <int name="autoDeletePeriodSeconds">300</int>
      <str name="ttlFieldName">time_to_live_s</str>
      <str name="expirationFieldName">expire_at_dt</str>
    </processor>  
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

I am trying to do atomic updates to existing docs in that collection to change the time to live.  I've tried both SolrJ and JSON update commands to set the value of time_to_live_s.  For example, it was +7DAYS, and I want to change it to +60DAYS.  Both SolrJ and JSON update produce exceptions:

```
responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":0},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.text.ParseException"],
    "msg":"Can't parse ttl as date math: {set=+60DAYS}",
    "code":400}}
```

The server log seems to suggest that rather than passing +60DAYS to the DateMathParser, the code is passing {set=+60DAYS} causing a ParseException.

Is it not possible to do an atomic update to the TTL field when the DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory is in the updateRequestProcessorChain?

If so, is it sufficient to simply update the computed (i.e., expire_at_dt) field to prevent the document from being deleted at the original 7 day expiration period?  I have tested that I can atomically update that field.

Comment: It seems the doc expiration update processor gets the partial document and doesn't know how to handle atomic updates on the ttl field. I would try to define it independently of the update chain, ie. as an `<updateProcessor/>`, and refer to it as a `post-processor` in the processor chain. That said, nothing prevents you from directly updating the expiration date field.